# Двоичная команда в SerialPort

Tags: c#, binary, byte

Добрый день. Подскажите как скормить двоичную команду функции SerialPort.Write();

Например по протоколу у меня команда 29h;

Comment: Последовательный порт работает с байтами, отправка байта со значением 0x29 - вероятно то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала понять, какого размера команда. Она [не бывает двоичной](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988), но у неё есть длина в байтах. Затем создать соответствующий массив байтов и послать его.

```
byte cmd = new byte[] { 0x29 };         // 1 байт
byte cmd = new byte[] { 0x29, 0x00 };   // Little indian, 2 байта
byte cmd = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x29 };   // Big indian, 2 байта
byte cmd = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x29); // Зависит от текущей архитектуры, 4 байта
```

```
sp.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length)
```

> Меня смутило одно , в расшифровке прокола написано: Формат сообщения: Байт 0: признак начала сообщения STX; Байт 1: длина сообщения (N) – ДВОИЧНОЕ число. В длину сообщения не включаются байты 0, LRC и этот байт; Байт 2: код команды или ответа – ДВОИЧНОЕ число; Байты 3...(N+1): параметры, зависящие от команды (могут отсутствовать); Байт N+2 – контрольная сумма сообщения – байт LRC – вычисляется поразрядным сложением (XOR) всех байтов сообщения (кроме байта 0).

```
const byte STX = 0; // Или чему там?
byte cmd = new byte[] { STX, default(byte), 0x29, default(byte) };
cmd[1] = cmd.Length - 3;
for (int q=1, last=cmd.Length-1; q<last; ++q) cmd[last] ^= cmd[q];
sp.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Меня смутило одно , в расшифровке прокола написано: Формат сообщения:
Байт 0: признак начала сообщения STX;
Байт 1: длина сообщения (N) – ДВОИЧНОЕ число. В длину сообщения не
включаются байты 0, LRC и этот байт;
Байт 2: код команды или ответа – ДВОИЧНОЕ число;
Байты 3...(N+1): параметры, зависящие от команды (могут отсутствовать);
Байт N+2 – контрольная сумма сообщения – байт LRC – вычисляется
поразрядным сложением (XOR) всех байтов сообщения (кроме байта 0).

Comment: @icedev нет двоичных и десятичных чисел. Есть число, есть двоичная форма его записи.

Comment: То есть в доках к протоколу ошибка?

Comment: @icedev, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @icedev не ошибка, просто "специфическое" использование термина "двоичный". Но как лучше - я тоже не знаю...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, лучше просто "число", а ещё лучше "однобайтовое число". А под двоичным они имели в виду, что передавать числом, а не строкой. В принципе, можно сказать "бинарное" - как "бинарные данные", что куда лучше, чем двоичное. Возможно, переводчики постарались, как всегда.

Comment: @Qwertiy понятно что они имели в виду :-) У нас тоже "бинарник" - ни разу не строка с двоичным представлением данных.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, но всё-таки он "бинарник", а не "двоичник" :) Как-то в русском языке бинарный и двоичный - не очень-то синонимы)

Comment: всем спасибо. более менее понятно.